# Missing PostgreSQL driver in rgdal: a long and sad story

Tags: postgis, postgresql, r, rgdal

This issue has been discussed few times and any of the read posts have not been the ultimate answer for my case:

I'm trying to load data from a **PostGIS** database into the R Console. While many packages in **R** are suitable for it, it seems to be that only **rgdal** is able to implement directly spatial capabilities.

The bad new is (as mentioned in many posts) the installation of **rgdal** from CRAN in windows does not include the driver **PostgreSQL** (the driver is not listed by the command `ogrDrivers()` in the R Console).

I loaded the source for **rgdal** from the CRAN site to build the package myself as recommended in some posts but I always get an error message:

```
OGR_write.cpp:1:24: fatal error: cpl_string.h: No such file or directory
```

The same error appears when trying to install the package from **GitHub**:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/rgdal")
```

Is there a way or a guide (for dummies) that can help me getting the PostgreSQL driver enabled in rgdal?

Further information that may be required to answer this question:

- My operative System: Windows 7 64-bit
- R-3.3.3 installed at C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3
- GDAL-2.0.1 installed at C:\Program Files\GDAL
- FWTools-2.2.8 installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.2.8
- Rtools-34 installed at C:\Rtools

Comment: try using osgeo4w instead of the now unsupported fwtools https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it, I have both **OSGeo4W** and **OSGeo4W64** installed direct on C:\. I just don't know how to build **rgdal** including the PostgreSQL driver in Windows...